# What is TabError and how can I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was making code editor and there is TabError.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
root = Tk("Note")

font_family = "Arial"
font_size = 18
def save_as():
    global text
    t = text_area.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    savelocation=asksaveasfilename()
    file1=open(savelocation, "w+")
    file1.write(t)
    file1.close()
def open():
    __file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", 
    filetypes = (("All Files","*.*"), 
    ("Text Documents","*.txt"),
    ("Python","*.py"),
    ("JavaScript","*.js"),
    ("HTML","*.html")))
    file = open(__file, "r")
    text_area.insert(1.0,file.read()) 
    file.close()
text_area = Text(root, font=(font_family + " " + str(font_size) ))
text_area.grid()
#menu
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
file_menu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save as", command=save_as)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open)
file_menu.add_separator()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please paste the actual error you see here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix indentation with tabs and spaces in your source code. If you do you get a TabError.

There is one other thing; the function `open()` is a builtin function and when you redefine it the original Python function will not be available to you. Call the function for opening files something else.